# Steam lacks a compatdata dir?

Tags: steam

[A lot of guides pertaining to getting Age of Empires 2 to run under Steam Proton](https://www.protondb.com/users/793747973) suggest dropping dlls into `~/.steam/steam/steamapps/compatdata/813780/pfx/drive_c/windows/system32`, however while I have a

```
~/.steam/steam/steamapps/
```

I do not have a

```
~/.steam/steam/steamapps/compatdata
```

What ever happened to `compatdata`?

Comment: Do you have any other Steam apps using Proton? I'm running **Worms Armageddon** with Proton 3.16 and that directory is there.

Comment: No, this is my first time using steam on Linux

Comment: OK - did you tell your Steam client to use Proton for Windows games? It's under Settings --> Steam Play.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old one, but I just run into this and thought it might help someone:

In Linux if you have Steam installed but you are using another hard disk or location for an extra library where you install the games, the default location wont exist:

```
~/.steam/steam/steamapps/compatdata
```

You can find it using the following method:

1. Right click Age of Empires II: Definitive Edition in the Steam Library
2. Go to Properties
3. In the window, click the LOCAL FILES tab
4. Click the BROWSE LOCAL FILES button
5. Go **up two directories**, to the `steamapps` one
6. There you can find the `compatdata` that was missing. The rest of the path is the same.
7. Backup the `ucrtbase.dll` file in the `system32` folder
8. Copy the `ucrtbase.dll` from the `vc_redist.x64.exe`

TL;DR: Go to your

`"custom Steam Library path"/steamapps/comptdata/813780/pfx/drive_c/windows/system32`

Answer (score 0):

If this directory does not exist, you can force Steam to create it,

- Go to library
- Right click on the game
- Go to "Force the use of a specific Steam Play compatibility tool"
- Click Proton 4

Then it'll save and install proton to your steam directory.